# Can't install Admob Plugin on PhoneGap Build Android App

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I used PhoneGap Build to build a simple android quiz game. Then, I tried to monetize it using Cordova-Admop pluggin. I first added it using`<gap:plugin name="phonegap-admob" source="npm"/>` in config.xml. However, when I upload the code to phonegap build website, I get the following error

> Error - A plugin you are using requires a preference: cdvCompileSdkVersion

can someone tell me what to do and give like a guide to how to install Admob properly...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to put a extra preference tag in your config.xml
These must be in your config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="15" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="12" />
```